# angularjs directive in ag-grid's IHeaderComponent?

Tags: ag-grid

Is there a way to add your own directive to the existing ag-grid's `IHeaderComponent` and modify the header content/behavior?

I created my own `IHeaderComponent` and used it in the ag-grid, but facing difficulty adding my own directive in the header. All the `TS` example on their site doesn't help much either, since I'm stuck with angular 1.6. In addition, what is the correct way to pass my dependencies to my `IHeaderComponent` since I cannot use `IHeaderAngularComponent`.

Any suggestions?

Edit: 
My first stab of it, kind a ugly how I pass my dependencies, not sure if that is the proper way to do it.

```
class MyHeader {
    /**
     * @implements {IHeaderComp}
     */

    constructor() {
        if (!MyHeader.injector) {
            MyHeader.injector = angular.element('[ng-app=myApp]').injector();
        }
        this.injector = MyHeader.injector;

        this.dependencies = ['$log'];
    }
    /**
     * @param {IHeaderCompParams} params
     */
    init(params) {
        this.params = params;
        this.eGui = document.createElement('div');
        this.eGui.innerHTML = '<span class="ag-header-cell-text" ref="eText" role="columnheader"></span>';

        this.eText = this.eGui.querySelector(".ag-header-cell-text");
        this.eText.textContent = params.displayName;

        this.initAngular();
    }

    initAngular() {
        this.dependencies = _.compact(this.dependencies);
        this.dependencies.forEach(dep => this[dep] = this.injector.get(dep));
    }

    getGui() {
        return this.eGui;
    }

    destroy() {
        if (this.params.enableSorting) {
            this.eGui.removeEventListener('click', this.sortRequestListener);
            this.params.column.removeEventListener('sortChanged', this.onSortChangedListener);
        }
    }

    onSortRequested(event) {
        if (this.params.enableSorting) {
            //...
        }
    }

    onSortChanged() {
        if (this.params.enableSorting) {
            //...
        }
    }

    initSorting() {
        if (this.params.enableSorting) {
            //...
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: provide pls a sample

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked an official demo for custom [`headerComponent`](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-header-rendering/#example-header-component)?

According to your code, to handle `click`, `hover` or any other `event` you need to define a `listener`. You are handling `dispose` with `removeEventListener`, which is good, but where is a `subscription`?

So as example, you need to append on init *step*:

```
let youHeader = this.eGui.querySelector(".ag-header-cell-text");
youHeader.addEventListener('click', this.youCustomClickHandler);

youCustomClickHandler(){
    ... your logic here
}
```

You can specify your `enable\disable` condition on init *step* (not exactly inside the `function`)

Comment: Yea, i have no problem getting the basic demo to work, is more like I am not sure how i can get my directive to trigger inside the `IHeaderComponent`. Say I do `.setAttribute('my-angular-directive', 'blah')`, what's the correct way to get it compile and digest?

Comment: You want to put your directive t custom component template?

Comment: Yeah. I want to put my directive into the `ref="eText"` element of the header. And since I cannot use IHeaderAngularComponent (stuck with old angularjs), not sure what's the way to do it.